# Exclude subdirectory of included directory with tar

Tags: tar

I'm trying to use `tar` and `xz` to make a compressed backup.  The command I currently have is:

```
tar --exclude="/home/derpy/Desktop/WineGames" \
    --exclude="/home/derpy/.steam" \
    --exclude="/home/derpy/Desktop/wesnoth-dev/.git" \
    --exclude="/home/derpy/Desktop/wesnoth-dev/build" \
    --exclude="/home/derpy/Desktop/wesnoth-dev/data" \
    --exclude="." \
    --create \
    --to-stdout \
    --preserve-permissions \
    --ignore-failed-read \
    --directory="/" \
    etc home boot root usr/share | \
xz \
    --lzma2=preset=9e,dict=1536MiB,mf=bt4,mode=normal,nice=273,depth=1000 \
    --to-stdout > \
    "/media/PentaSet/Backups/"(date +"%m-%d-%Y@%I:%M:%S%p")".tar.xz"
```

However, for some reason when I run the command, the `.steam` directory is still being included in the output archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing full path names on the `--exclude` but *relative* pathnames in the directories to tar up

eg

```
--exclude="/home/derpy/.steam"
home
```

Because you're specifing `home` the filename `tar` sees is `home/derpy/.steam` and *not* `/home/derpy/.steam`.

All of your exlcudes should use the filename that would match the name inside the tar file; eg `home/derpy/.steam`